# How extract all the jars needed for a maven project to a folder?

Tags: maven, jar

I’m trying to de-mavenize a project.

Is there a way to extract all the jars needed for this maven project to a folder?

(I’m very newbie with maven, so please; instructions provided should be in dummy mode) Thanks!

;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [dependency:copy-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) goal of [maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) to achieve this.

In fact, just run `mvn dependency:dependencies` on your maven project and you should find a `dependencies` subfolder created under `target` folder and populated with all the dependencies including transitive ones.

Comment: There's a little problem with it if you use Maven 3. Maven 3 uses new dependency resolution mechanism (based on Aether) while `maven-dependency-plugin` still uses the old one (from Maven 2). So you're not sure if a resolution is the real one when using the plugin. And, in fact, I've had some problems because of this issue when switching project from Maven 2 to 3, so this is not only just hypothetical case.

Comment: How this runs on earth today, I guess only God knows?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `maven-assembly-plugin` and its `jar-with-dependencies` predefined descriptor:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies

You can easily create own descriptor by modify this one slightly. Just set `<unpack>false</unpack>` and `<outputDirectory>/some-dir</outputDirectory>`.

And if you haven't used this plugin so far, read this:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html
to get what's actually going on there and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the way Maven will work. Maven has the following prerequisits:

- Maven installation with binary (of course)
- Maven repository that caches needed JARs and stores created JARs.

So perhaps it should be possible to generate e.g. a WAR file, that will contain "all nededed JAR files".

Maven does not manage only the JARs needed for runtime, but also the plugins needed to run Maven, and all JARs that are needed during the Maven process (like unit tests, coverage, quality checks, ...).

Perhaps you should make your question more concrete, I will update my answer then as well.

Comment: I achieve that in a handy crafted way:
 1) Adding this line to the settins.xml:  <localRepository>C:/TEMP/repo</localRepository>
2) Doing a *.jar search in that folder. 
3) Copying jars founded to a separate folder (C:/TEMP/jars)

Comment: Well, so you now have far more jars in `C:/TEMP/jars` than you actually need. For example, you have a lot of stuff needed by basic Maven plugins (like compiler itself). It probably works, however, because all needed jars are there.