# Missing Java Jakarta Persistence provider outside the container (stand alone Jave SE application)

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-migration

I get the following exception

```java
ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.persistence.Persistencee
```

This error happens in my standalone Java web-app I am trying to use JPA with it. I have normally used JPA in a container and have done for years. You can view a very simple app here: (https://github.com/pramodShehan5/jpa-example ) that displays the same behavior.

File `pom.xml` contains the following dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core-jakarta</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.14.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When this sample app is compiled with `mvn compile` all is fine.

```bash
cd target/classes
java org.example.Main
```

Error

```java
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/persistence/Persistence
        at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:21)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.persistence.Persistence
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
```

So the problem as I see it is I need a provider added into my jar and this is where I need help. Can anyone point out what I need to add to my pom file to give me a provider (assuming that is really what I am missing) or do I just need to get one of the GlassFish JARs on the classpath to do this for me?

Comment: You ask a question related to container, but you did not show your `Dockerfile`. You command came to error as expected, because Jakarta EE did not in classpath.

Comment: If you want to run your project using `java` not `mvn`, then you can collect all the dependent JARs you need (the transitive dependencies downloaded by your POM). See [How extract all the jars needed for a maven project to a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10294070/12567365), and probably similar questions. Then, make sure these are all on the classpath of your `java` command - something like: `java -cp lib/*.jar java.org.example.Main`

Comment: Did you include the Jakarta Persistence API as a dependency?

Comment: @BasilBourque I did In the example I mentioned the app was able to satisfy the dependencies from <artifactId>hibernate-core-Jakarta</artifactId>,  the issue I think is that I am missing a runtime dependency I am not sure what to resolve it with.

Comment: @andrewJames I believe all the dependencies should be in the jar

Comment: @RaphaëlColantonio Sorry, that was misleading, I was referring to a Java EE Container (Payara or Glassfish for example)

Comment: What jar do you mean? The command in the question (`java org.example.Main`) does not refer to any jar. Also the jar would need to have been built as a "fat" jar. Was it built that way?

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case it was a matter of putting all the jars that it needs (that would normally be provided by the container) in the modules directory and calling the app like this:

java --class-path "modules/*" --module-path modules com.smartphonedev.mqttlistener.MQTTClient